# angular polymer if else condition for div element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, polymer

i have polymer template in which i have 3 divs . i want to keep condition on based on name m fetching in expression. How to keep condition for the same. 
code is below:

```
<div class="cySimplifiedContainer isCostLabel">
    <span>{{item.id.optnName}}</span>
</div>
<div class="isSummary">
    <span class="iSHeader">{{_toMoneyFormat(item.optnCtd)}}</span>
</div>
<div class="isSummary">
    <span class="iSHeader">{{_toMoneyFormat(item.optnGoFwd)}}</span>
</div>
<div class="isSummary">
    <span class="iSHeader">{{_toMoneyFormat(item.optnTotal)}}</span>
</div>
```

I need to keep check on item.id.optnName . If it contains KEFH then it should remove _toMoneyFormat function from span.
plz review .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand do you want to remove a div tag if a condition is met? If that is the case have you tried ng-if?

Comment: i want to remove _toMoneyFormat function in span when condition is met. i tried ng-if condition like this    <div class="isSummary">
                    <span class="iSHeader" ng-if="item.id.optnName == 'TSLSV KEFH'">{{_toMoneyFormat(item.optnCtd)}}</span>
                    <span class="iSHeader" ng-if="item.id.optnName != 'TSLSV KEFH'">{{item.optnCtd}}</span>
                </div>  but it is creating 2 span . and i want only 1 span

Comment: its not working still i am getting 2 span. check my code:                                <div class="isSummary">
                    <span  ng-if="item.id.optnName.search('KEFH') === -1">{{_toMoneyFormat(item.optnCtd)}}</span>
                    <span  ng-if="item.id.optnName.search('KEFH') !== -1">{{item.optnCtd}}</span>
                </div>                                                                                         in output i need only one span

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-if` in your div. Here i create a simple `ng-if` example

[plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2slUDjnGXUAhzHdvHSTO?p=preview)

for more information read [AngularJS/ng-if doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)